# Trying to figure out why i got this error 442

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, server, syntax-error, weblogic

> {"Error"."the remote server returned a error".(442) unprocessableeinity".",info:""",extra:""","http_status ",442

It's on an android device google chrome. Is there a solution to it?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO. Please refer to this document on how to ask a well-formed question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) might help.